# 2D line intersection point with a bounding box

Tags: graphics, trigonometry

What would be an efficient algorithm for calculating the intersection point of a line starting a (x,y), with an angle of θ, and a bounding rectangle with co-orindates (0,0 to w,h)?  Assuming the line origin is within the box.

In basic ascii art (for a line starting at 2,6 and θ approx 9π/8):

```
 h---------------...h,w
 .               ...
 .               ... 
 .               ...
 7               ...
 6   x           ...
 5  /            ...
 4 /             ...
 3/              ...
 2               ...
/1               ...
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ... w
```

All variables, except θ, are integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume we parametrize the line with a variable `t`, i.e. each point on the line can be written as

```
[x(t),y(t)] = [x,y] + t * [dx,dy]
```

with constants

```
dx = cos(theta)
dy = sin(theta)
```

Then you can first calculate the cut through the vertical boundaries:

```
if dx<0 then        // line going to the left -> intersect with x==0
  t1 = -x/dx
  x1 = 0
  y1 = y + t1*dy
else if dx>0 then   // line going to the right -> intersect with x==w
  t1 = (w-x)/dx
  x1 = w
  y1 = y + t1*dy
else                // line going straight up or down -> no intersection possible
  t1 = infinity
end
```

where `t1` is the distance to the intersection point and `[x1,y1]` the point itself. Second you do the same for the upper and lower boundaries:

```
if dy<0 then        // line going downwards -> intersect with y==0
  t2 = -y/dy
  x2 = x + t2*dx
  y2 = 0
else if dy>0 then   // line going upwards -> intersect with y==h
  t2 = (h-y)/dy
  x2 = x + t2*dx
  y2 = h
else
  t2 = infinity
end
```

Now you just have to select the point with less distance from your origin `[x,y]`.

```
if t1 < t2 then
  xb = x1
  yb = y1
else
  xb = x2
  yb = y2
end
```

Note that this algorithm only works if the starting point is inside the bounding box, i.e. `0 <= x <= w` and `0 <= y <= h`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that doesn't work.  E.g. For (x,y)=(8,3) and 0=7π/5 (near horizontal to the left) this will return a boundary point of (xb,yb)=(7.02,0), whereas it should be (0,0.40).  I think.

Comment: @Chris Leishman: You seem to use a different notion of theta. In my example the angle is measured counter-clock-wise from the x-axis (i.e. zero is left, pi/2 up) while you measure it clock-wise from the y-axis (i.e. zero is up and pi/2 to the left). You can easily replace theta by pi/2-theta and the formulas are fine with your definition.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't clear on the angle origin, although my ascii example does hint at it.  Would you say it's more common to apply sin(0) to the horizontal axis (as I assumed) or to the vertical (as you have)?